# displaytag exporting showing whole HTML tag(for hyperlink)

Tags: styles, export, displaytag

I'm using displaytag tld for displaying tables and exporting.
The problem is, in my first column, the column content is hyperlink,
and all of this html tag is generated on exporting.

```
<a class="ajax"
id="msgIDPkView"
href="displaySelect
DashboardDetailsV
iewFullText.do?ref=
501250">501250</
a>
```

How can I make it only show the value(between ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only decorator for this column use this:

```
<display:setProperty name="export.decorated" value="false"/>
```

with this property the decorator doesn't apply to your column while printing!

otherwise you've to create two columns for this property; one to show in web browser and one to show in export!

```
<display:column property="id" media="html">
<display:column property="id" media="csv">
```

Comment: I've it's manual pdf!
you can download it from here:[link](http://www.displaytag.org/10/displaytag.pdf)

Comment: @ROROROOROROR 
 Even i too have same issue but here I have hyperlink <a
href="/ABCD/rse/getData.action?idDtl=1>1212121</a>. This value create in action class and displayed in jsp but Hyperlink as it is showing in exported pdf/excel file. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don’t use old tech!